# TFS API: Clone Build Definition Environment

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to clone an existing environment within a build definition.

This is possible through the TFS GUI, but it doesn't seem like the API natively supports it.

So far, I've tried the following (in PowerShell):

## Download build definition and deserialize

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$pwd\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")

$TargetDefinitionName = "Name"

$TargetDefinitionID = ($DefinitionsOverview | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $TargetDefinitionName } | Select-Object -First 1).id

$TargetDefinitionURL = "$TfsUri/$TargetDefinitionID"

$TargetDefinitionJSON = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$TargetDefinitionURL" -UseDefaultCredentials

$DeserializedBuildDefinition = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::DeserializeObject($TargetDefinitionJSON.Content)

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.ToString()
```

## Duplicate JSON block that represents environment, change unique properties

```
$NewEnvironmentString = $DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments[4].ToString()

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments.Add(5)

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments[5] = $NewEnvironmentString 

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments[5].name.value = "NewEnvironment"

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments[5].rank.value = "6"

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.environments[5].id.value = "1665"

$DeserializedBuildDefinition.revision.value = "20"
```

## Serialize JSON and post back (with new environment)

```
$SerializedBuildDefinition = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($DeserializedBuildDefinition)

$PostData = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($SerializedBuildDefinition)

$Headers = @{ "Accept" = "api-version=2.0-preview" }

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri 
$TargetDefinitionURL -Headers $Headers `
          -Method Put -Body $PostData -ContentType "application/json"

$Response.StatusDescription
```

PROBLEM: $Response.StatusDescription gives "OK," but no new environment appears in the build definition.

One thought is that, in addition to 'name,' 'ID,' and 'rank, there are other values that need to be unique per environment that I'm missing.

I've also tried cloning the environment manually, saving the JSON representation of the definition, deleting the environment, and posting the JSON back. The new environment still doesn't show up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to import a JSON parsing library. Use `Invoke-RestMethod` and the resulting JSON is automatically converted into a PowerShell `PSCustomObject`

Comment: https://blogs.infosupport.com/modifying-tfs2015-build-definitions-using-powershell/  "Although the standard ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json cmdlets are fine for basic JSON querying, when used to convert a JSON build definition to a PSCustomObject and then back to a JSON string again, the resulting JSON string is not accepted by the TFS2015 rest endpoint – it could have something to do with the behaviour discussed here on UserVoice.

So instead, we’ll use the widely-known Newtonsoft.Json library to do the manipulation with. To use it from your Powershell script, do the following:"

Comment: Do you mean you want to clone a environment from a **release** definition? Which version of tfs are you using?

Comment: Yes, technically it’s a “release” definition. It’s TFS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Future: Yaml based build definitions as code are well on their way, at least to VSTS. This won't help an immediate need but probably offers a better and more lightweight future approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy an environment, you need to change "id", "name", and "rank". **And the “id” need to be changed to "0"**. Also, try to use api-version=**2.3-preview.1**.

Then use the [api of update a release definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#update-a-release-definition) to update the definition:

```
PUT http://tfs2015:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection/teamProject/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=2.3-preview.1
{
  ……
}
```

I have tested with TFS 2015 Update 4. Api could clone an environment successfully.

Comment: Thank you Cece. I will give this a shot in the morning.

Comment: Please let us know whether it helps you after you test it.

Comment: Setting the ID to 0 and using the 2.3-preview.1 version of the API allowed the environment to be cloned.  However, I assumed that the build steps would be cloned as well.  Do I need to set each task ID to 0 if I want to clone them along with the environment? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @blashmet No, you need to change the ID of deployStep to 0. `"deployStep": {
                "tasks": [..],"id":0}`

Comment: @blashmet As Starian mentioned, you also need to change the ID of deployStep to 0. In this way, you would be able to clone build steps as well.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - That worked, however, if I try to clone the same environment again (using a different name), I receive a new error.  For example, suppose that I run the script once, cloning environment DR to DR2, and then again, cloning DR to DR3.  The first run works, but the second run generates the following error.  It's as if TFS recognizes that the first clone didn't work properly: Invoke-WebRequest : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402869: Release definition environment 'DR2' needs to have at least one preDeploy and postDeploy approvals. Add it and try 
again...."

Comment: Go to web portal to see if there is such message too and fix it. Then try again.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - There is no similar message in the web portal. Even if there was, though, I would want to fix it during the clone of DR2, and not manually afterwards.  Do I need to add something to the script that adds a "preDeploy" and "postDeploy" approval to the cloned environments? If the approvals aren't defined in the JSON, then the cloned environments won't inherit them. Maybe there's another API call I need to make to add them?

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool for cloning TFS builds, as (with TFS 2015 update 1 at least) the web 'clone' function does not clone the 'Repository' or 'Triggers' tab. Some of our build steps were a little complicated so I also wrote some simple transforms to automatically set the values according to the target branch.

I used the `BuildHttpClient` object in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi` assembly to get the original build definition (`BuildDefinition` object, using `GetDefinitionAsync()` method), transform any build steps values, then call `CreateDefinitionAsync()` on `BuildHttpClient` to create the new build.

Works very reliably and under the hood it appears to use the TFS REST API.

If there was any interest, I'd be happy to create a more in depth tutorial on this.